# times of deviation US8708791B2

Tags: patent-infringement

I read the patent multiple times but getting confused with the claim point "analyzing, by the at least one game server, the game play data to determine individual players' typical gaming styles and times of deviation from the typical gaming styles; and
comparing, by the at least one game server, times of deviation from players' typical gaming styles to determine instances of probable collusion between players"

https://patents.google.com/patent/US8708791B2/en

Comment: I am confused by your post. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

This patent is pretty long and complicated, but I'm gathering from a cursory review that the part of the claim you are getting hung up on means that the game method being described by the claim is determining that a players playing style changes in a significant way suggesting the player is colluding with other players and thus is cheating.

A patent's claims are described by the rest of the patent. To better comprehend how the game method works you'll need to read the specifics as described in the "DETAILED DESCRIPTION OF THE INVENTION" section. In particular figure 7 seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful advice!